# Hide search box on site settings and Add an app page

Tags: sharepoint-server, master-page, search-box

I am creating a custom master page and I have a default search box in the header. I will be using same master page as site and system master page. Currently search box is visible on all pages. But "seattle.master" doesn't show a search box on the 'site settings' and 'Add an App' page. Can I hide search box on site settings and "Add an App" page?

Answer (score 1):

The probably simplest method would be to add the following CSS to your masterpage, assuming your custom searchbox has an HTML element ID of `#Searchbox`:

```
<style>
#aspnetForm[action*="settings.aspx"] #SearchBox,
#aspnetForm[action*="addanapp.aspx"] #SearchBox
{
  display: none;
}
</style>
```